# PrimeNG datatable custom filter on input for object

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a PrimeNG datatable with dynamic columns and I want to add a filter to these columns filtering for the value.

Here is my datatable column with the filter :

```
    <p-column *ngFor="let param of searchFilters" [style]="{'width':'auto'}" header="{{param.name}}"
              [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search">
        <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
            <input type="text" (keyup)="dt.onFilterKeyup($event.target.value, param.name, 'contains')"/>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-col let-user="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <span>
             {{getUserAttributeCaseInsensitive(user.attributes, param.name)}}
          </span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

My User object which represents the data for the datatable looks something like this :

```
User {
    id?: number;
    attributes?: Object;
}
```

And in this attributes object you can find the values for each column. The searchFilters used for the `*ngFor` to build each column is dynamically build and does not always contain everything that the attributes object contains. Now because it is an object I can not set the `field="attribute[param.name]"` (from the `*ngFor`). So I tried a custom filter which does not work either.

Can somebody help ?